# Read only assignment String c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to assign "tela[counter] = letra.ToString();", but it shows up the following error message "Property or indexer 'string.this[int] cannot be assigned to -- it is read only".

I saw some topics saying that you have to define {get;set;} to the atribute, but I've done this, and it didn't work.

[OBS] I tried to create get and set methods but the problem persisted

```
     public String tela { get; set; }

    private void btnSendWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char letra = Convert.ToChar(txtGetWord.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(comboPalavra[0]);
        Boolean codigoVerificador;
        codigoVerificador =  verificador.VerificaLetra(comboPalavra[0],letra);
        if (codigoVerificador == true)
        {

            foreach(char c in comboPalavra[0].ToCharArray())
            {
                counter++;
                if(c == letra)
                {
                    tela[counter] = letra.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Nao contem");
    }
```

Comment: You can't change content of the string with indexer. Create a new string rather (with StringBuilder for example)

Comment: There's several things wrong with this. I suggest picking up a book on C# and reading it. Guessing is not considered good coding practice.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093976/property-or-indexer-string-thisint-cannot-be-assigned-to-its-read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093976/property-or-indexer-string-thisint-cannot-be-assigned-to-its-read-only) This should help..

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, meaning that you can't change a variable's value without creating a new string.

You are trying to change a single character in a string here, which is not allowed:

```
tela[counter] = letra.ToString();
```

A solution to this is to use `StringBuilder`. You can think of it as a mutable version of `string`.

You can declare a `StringBuilder` outside the loop:

```
var telaBuilder = new StringBuilder(tela);
```

In the loop, change the erroneous line to:

```
telaBuilder[counter] = letra;
```

And after the loop, assign `telaBuilder` to `tela`:

```
tela = telaBuilder.ToString();
```

Don't forget `using System.Text`!

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature of the indexer for a `string`:

```
public char this[int index] { get; }
```

See that it returns a `char` and only has a `get`, that means it is readonly and you cannot assign something to it. This is why you are getting the error.

If you want to replace a specific letter in a string at a specific position, you can do it like this:

```
var name = "ferry Seinfeld";
char[] nameArray = name.ToArray();
nameArray[0] = 'J';
name = new string(nameArray);
```

Please look into [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `String` and also look into [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class to see if those will suit your needs.